# How to apply formula in specific condition in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to use flags to use in formulas 1 ,0 . I want excel to put 1 every specific number of months (3,6,...) .

so if 1 applies in Sep ,then I want another 1 to be after (3,6,...) months. the number of months will be filled in a cell related to that row.

```
    Sep-14  Oct-14  Nov-14  Dec-14  Jan-15 Feb-15   Mar-15  Apr-15  May-15  Jun-15
```

3         1                     1                        1                       1
6          1                                              1

please help
thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question makes no sense to me. Can you please try to rewrite it and add more information so we all understand what you're seaking for? I'm sure it is possible to write you a formula, but with the information that currently is given, I have no idea what you want so I can't make you a formula either.

Comment: thanks,i want to apply a specific formula every a specific number of months... so excel applies the formula every 3 months for example

Comment: Okay so what have you tried already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: im not able to make excel apply formula when I specify the number of months needed to pass

Comment: So you would have, say in col A, a number that represents the interval (for example, 3).  Then in the column for some particular month, you would place a 1 to indicate that it is the starting month.  You would want Excel to place a 1 in the column for the third month after that, and every subsequent third month?  Your string of numbers (31111611) doesn't seem to relate in any way to what you described.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have a conditional formula, a formula that applies when a certain condition is met.

In programming this is called an IF statement.

IF something is true, THEN something happens, ELSE something else happens.

Excel has an IF formula as well.

```
=IF(condition ; if true ; else)
```

at `condition` you place your formula to check whether the month applies to your condition, for example `mod(A1;3)=0`; which checks for every 3 months that are entered in A1.

at `if true` you enter your formula that you want to run when the flag is set.

at `else` you enter what the output should be when the flag is not set.

Example:

```
=IF(MOD(a1;3)=0;2+2;"0")
```

This formula will enter a 4 in this cell if the month in a1 is met your condition, or a 0 if not.

*Sorry if this is not what you're after, but this is what I could make up from what you want. If not, please be more specific.*